# Trouble getting feed item from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, last.fm

I'm trying to retrieve album artwork from the Last.FM API using JSON and jQuery Ajax, but I'm having trouble accessing the data structure, which looks like:

```
  "image":[
     {
        "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/82993237.png",
        "size":"small"
     },
     {
        "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/82993237.png",
        "size":"medium"
     },
     {
        "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/174s\/82993237.png",
        "size":"large"
     },
     {
        "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/82993237.png",
        "size":"extralarge"
     },
     {
        "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/_\/82993237\/Jake+Bugg.png",
        "size":"mega"
     }
  ],
```

Full URL: http://lab.starchcreative.co/zapp/albumartproxy.php?artist=Jake%20Bugg&album=Jake%20Bugg

This data is nested inside `album` as well, so I tried to do this to access the artwork URL for *mega*: `albumArtURL = data.album.image.#text[4];`

This returned an error as I had `#` in the item. So I just tried `albumArtURL = data.album.image.text[4];` to no avail.

Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use bracket notation (instead of *dot*) for the problematic `#text`
and accessing the `image`'s `[4]` array place before targeting the object key

```
albumArtURL = data.album.image[4]["#text"];
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data.album.image[4]["#text"]` instead?

Comment: Boom. You're a life saver!

Comment: @JAM depends on how tired you are ;) thx

Answer (score 0):

```
   $.each(images.image, function (i, item) {
     var myvar = "text: " + item['#text'] + " size: " + item.size 
    })
```

here is a working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kemalemin/G5gv2/)